# CSS to disable native widget for select/option

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a custom selector control and am trying to create a more semantically correct DOM. So what I want is to be able to use `<select>` and `<option>` elements in the DOM. The problem is that I have no idea how to remove their special status -- to make them render as normal blocks and not as a selection box.

I'm only interested in a standards compliant solution, since before I go browser specific I'd just revert back to using `div` blocks instead and forget about proper semantics.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript

Comment: @Danko, thanks. I guess that makes the answer "No, there is no compliant way to do it."

Comment: Yep as I know is still a little bit complicated to style in a free way that kind of components with a crossbrowser and effective solution.